# Mobile friendly wrapper for website

Tags: javascript, html, css, mobile, wrapper

So I have this idea in mind. There is a website I visit frequently, but that isn't optimized for mobile devices in any way.

So I had the idea of creating a userscript to optimize it a little. Unfortunately there is no possibility for userscripts on the iPhone.

Then I came up with the idea to write a wrapper page for the website (where I would host that wrapper page on my webspace). I liked this idea much more, because I wanted not only to modify the content to optimize it for mobile access, but I also wanted to add some tags to enable putting it as an icon on my homescreen and to adjust scrolling behaviour and such.

Then I realized, that this was most probably impossible due to cross domain policy.

So, is there any possibility, to kind of "wrap" a website to add some tags and css (and if possible even add/overwrite some javascript) in order to make it mobile friendly?

Any suggestions and help much appreciated!

Comment: This is what media queries are for - http://www.sitepoint.com/web-foundations/media-queries/

Comment: Hey Jeff! Thanks for your comment. Can you please elaborate a bit? I can't see how this helps me with my problem of modifying the css and adding html tags to a page that I don't control.